# Pairwise similarities with numpy without for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to calculate similarities between each row using `numpy`. Would you please advice how this can be done without for loop?

```
import numpy as np


x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])     # input:  2 x 3 matrix
similarity_matrix = np.zeros([2, 2])     # output: 2 x 2 matrix

for i, row1 in enumerate(x):
    for j, row2 in enumerate(x):
        similarity_matrix[i, j] = my_similarity_func(row1, row2) # this func returns a scalar
```

If my input is n x 1 matrix, then this works. Is there a way to achieve this when input is n x m matrix?

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
similarity_matrix = my_similarity_func(*np.meshgrid(x, x))
```

*I am aware that there are some libraries to calculate similarities such as `sklearn` or `scipy`. Also there exists a fancy linear algebra way. But here I am simply wondering if it is possible to replace this for loop.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html?

Comment: Wouldn't you agree this depends on the similarity metric being used? Also, there are many distance measures in `scipy.spatial.distance`.

Comment: Yes I am aware that `scipy ` can do this. I need to implement my own similarity function. My questions is not regarding the distance calculation. I just want to know if this is possible without for loop.

Comment: .... you can implement your own `ufunc` where you write the for-loop in C. You'll need a for-loop somewhere. But with no knowledge of `my_similarity_func` then there's no way to get around this loop

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Or, better, in Cython.

Comment: @abarnert sure, Cython is generally easier. Also, some auxiliary JIT like `numba` might help with performance

Comment: @E.K. To answer your question, no.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the for-loop using `itertools`, which may be more efficient (I'm assuming efficiency is your actual goal):

```
from itertools import product, starmap
it = starmap(my_similarity_func, product(x, x))
similarity_matrix = np.fromiter(it, float).reshape((len(x), len(x)))
```

Comment: This is probably the worst thing you could do to improve efficiency with numpy...

Comment: @COLDSPEED *Improving* efficiency is relative to the starting point - i.e. the two for loops above. Also OP hasn't actually stated their goal.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, have you benchmarked this, or is it a best guess based on experience?

Comment: @user2699 In my (admittedly limited) experience, optimising the function you call gets you a lot further than optimising the code that calls it because that's where the bottleneck lies.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, that's a good point.  I was only considering the overhead of looping, which probably isn't much on an array the size given.  I guess it really depends on how efficient the similarity function is.

Answer (score 1):

A couple options have been giving for removing the `for` loops.
Assuming this is due to concerns about efficiency, I've provided some benchmarks.
Profiling this sort of thing is very dependent on what the function being called does and how large the array is.
Timing several of the methods given here (using `np.dot` as the similarity function) gives pretty similar results, with the for loop being surprisingly competitive.

```
%timeit tmp=test_using_for_loop(x)
5.88 µs ± 164 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit array([[my_similarity_func(r1, r2) for r1 in x] for r2 in x])
6.54 µs ± 101 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit it = starmap(my_similarity_func, product(x, x)); similarity_matrix = np.fromiter(it, float).reshape((len(x), len(x)))
5.34 µs ± 364 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit dist.cdist(x,x,metric=my_similarity_func)
15 µs ± 136 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

On the other hand, the data given is rather small.
In many applications it is typical to compute a similarity metric on hundreds or thousands of samples.
And after all, why optimize for a 2 by 3 matrix?
Using larger data

```
x = np.random.randn(3000, 150)
```

The results are

```
%timeit tmp=test_using_for_loop(x)
5.69 s ± 54.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit array([[my_similarity_func(r1, r2) for r1 in x] for r2 in x])
5.17 s ± 29.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit it = starmap(my_similarity_func, product(x, x)); similarity_matrix = np.fromiter(it, float).reshape((len(x), len(x)))
3.74 s ± 20.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit dist.cdist(x,x,metric=my_similarity_func)
8.08 s ± 156 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

There's also the question brought up by coldspeed and several other commenters - would it be better to optimize the similarity function rather than how it is called?
A custom similarity function will not be as optimized as `np.dot`.
So, using what is a purposefully worst-case (and absolutely useless) similarity function

```
def my_similarity_func(a,b):
    calc1 = a.dot(b)
    calc2 = sqrt(abs(sum(a)+sum(b)))
    calc3 = calc1**2 / calc2 + 1
    return calc3
```

What was a fairly substantial difference in performance almost disappears.  The percent difference between the itertools method and basic looping is around 5 or 6% (still larger than expected, but not much)

```
%timeit tmp=test_using_for_loop(x)
1min 11s ± 2.02 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit array([[my_similarity_func(r1, r2) for r1 in x] for r2 in x])
1min 7s ± 468 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit array([[my_similarity_func(r1, r2) for r1 in x] for r2 in x])
1min 7s ± 322 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit array([[my_similarity_func(r1, r2) for r1 in x] for r2 in x])
1min 8s ± 1.31 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

In summary, there are several ways to remove the for loop but performance-wise they will probably all be similar.
If performance matters it would be best to re-write the similarity function in a way that can take advantage of broadcasting or other optimizations.
Doing that to the worst-case similarity function here reduces the running time to a few hundred milliseconds.

```
%timeit x.dot(x.T)**2 / sqrt(abs(sum(x, 1)[:,None] + sum(x.T, 0))) + 1
128 ms ± 3.14 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```